# How to exclude the master branch from the GitLab 13 ci build process?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I want the build process to run for all branches when I add a tag. Except for the master branch.

```
deploy_qas:
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - echo "Implatado em QAS"
  environment:
    name: qas
    url: https://env.br
  only:
  - tags
  except:
  - master
```

This way it is not working.

I am using GitLab 13 ce.

Answer (score 0):

The new Gitlab syntax uses [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules).

> `only` and `except` are not being actively developed. `rules` is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.

Solution with `rules`:

```yaml
deploy_qas:
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - echo "Implatado em QAS"
  environment:
    name: qas
    url: https://env.br
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG  
      # `when: always` is implied here
```